# Flask: Mock call to external component returns a non serializable object for a HTTP response

Tags: python, json, flask, redis, mocking

I'm trying to learn how to use the Mock library in python.

I have a Flask application which is connected to Redis via redis-py package.

In the '/myapp/version' API of my app, I call a info() from redis-py, and format a HTTP response back where the JSON data includes also the return data from the info() call:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from redis import StrictRedis

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = StrictRedis(host='redis', port=6379)

@app.route('/myapp/version', methods=['GET'])
def get_version():
    redis_info = redis.info() #returns a dict
    return jsonify({
        'app_version': '0.1',
        'flask_version': '0.11.1',
        'redis_info': redis_info
    })
```

And this is my test.py, which uses the Flask test_client:

```
import json
import mock
import redis
import myapp import app

class TestApp:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(self):
        self.client = app.test_client()
        self.client.testing = True

    @mock.patch.object(redis.StrictRedis, 'info')
    def test_get_version(self, mock_info):
        result = self.client.get('/myapp/version')
        assert result.status_code == 200
        mock_info.assert_called()
```

If I launch nosetests, the response from the HTTP request will return error:

```
TypeError: <MagicMock name='info()' id='140548379595472'> is not JSON serializable
```

I guess that the problem is that the info() call is correctly mocked, but then it cannot be serialzed to JSON to format the response by the Flask test client.

Is there a way to get a valid response anyway? Or maybe I am using Mock in the wrong way? I know it is handy in unit test but here it'm more like integration testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to mock `redis-py` package is ti use `mockredis`. You need to simply patch your method using: `@patch('redis.StrictRedis', mock_strict_redis_client)`. More info can be found on the project [page](https://github.com/locationlabs/mockredis).

Once you patched `redis`, you can setup the value of specific keys required for your application as if you're using `redis`. This will enable you to control what values should be returned from the various redis calls and will ensure that your application will work properly.

In your specific case, the call for redis that is being done somewhere in your app might be returning the magic mock instead of some serializable `json`.

You can control the return value of the call by using `mock_info.return_value = json_str`

Comment: Very interesting. If I understand correctly, in this case @patch does some kind of dependency override from the actual StrictRedis call to a stub, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Correct. The stub is the object you added as argument to your test method. (I updated my answer with a way to control the return value of such call)

Comment: The bad side is that this package mockredis has a non-existing documentation. Just a readme of 30 lines :( I will have to try to understand  how to use directly from the code. Thanks.